# Switch case does not trigger c# asp net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I made this popup that does not trigger the button I want it to. The user selects a contact, the contact is displayed with a delete button, when clicked, the confirmation popup appears with two more buttons, "Yes" and "No", they do not trigger for some reason.

ASPX:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptList_OnItemCommand" ID="rptList">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table id="tblListContact">
        <tr id="tblRowContact">
            <th>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTName" />
            </th>
        </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>

<td>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="selectContact" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'><%# Eval("Name") %></asp:LinkButton>
</td>
    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="deleteContact" ID="btnDelete" CommandName="deleteContact" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="return OpenPopup(this)">
    <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Deleted-16x16.png" ID="DeleteContact" runat="server" />
    </asp:LinkButton>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h3 class="modalHdr">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTRemove users" /></h3>
        <p>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTDelete Contact"></asp:Label>
        </p>
            <asp:Button CommandName="noBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="ButtonNo" runat="server" Text="TRNSLTNo" CssClass="popupConfirm" />
            <asp:Button CommandName="yesBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="ButtonYes" runat="server" Text="TRNSLTYes" CssClass="popupConfirm" />
    </div>
</div>

</ItemTemplate>
```

C#:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Assigning commands to repeater.
    /// </summary>
    protected void rptList_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var contactId = Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument);

        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "selectContact":
                divRead.Visible = true;
                ContactId = contactId;
                var getContact = _ecSystem.GetContact(contactId);

                if (getContact != null)
                {
                    lblName.Text = getContact.Name;
                    lblPhone.Text = getContact.PhoneNumber;
                    lblMobile.Text = getContact.Cellphone;
                    lblAdress.Text = getContact.Street;
                    lblNotes.Text = getContact.Notes;
                    lblPage.Text = getContact.Homepage;
                    lblEmail.Text = getContact.Email;

                    imgPhone.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblPhone.Text);
                    imgMobile.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblMobile.Text);
                    imgAddress.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblAdress.Text);
                    imgNotes.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblNotes.Text);
                    imgPage.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblPage.Text);
                    imgEmail.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblEmail.Text);
                }
                break;

            case "deleteContact": //It never comes to these statements
                ContactId = contactId;
                break;

            case "noBtn": //It never comes to these statements
                break;

            case "yesBtn": //It never comes to these statements
                if (ContactId != null)
                {
                    _ecSystem.DeleteContact(ContactId.Value);
                }
                ContactId = null;
                Response.Redirect("Contact.aspx");
                break;

            case "editContact":
                divAdd.Visible = true;
                _editMode = true;
                var contacts = _ecSystem.GetContact(contactId);
                if (contacts != null)
                {
                    ViewState["Contacts"] = contacts;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

jQuery:

```
function OpenPopup($this) {
    if ($($this).attr("disabled") === "disabled") {
        return false;
    }
    var module = $($this).parent().find("#myModal");
    module.show();
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target === module) {
            module.hide();
        }
    };

    return false;
}
```

Comment: There are typos in your `CommandNames`, f.e.it's `deleteContact`

Comment: So where should I change?

Comment: well, they should be the same

Comment: Can you create a post and explain?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? ASPX: `<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="deleteContact"...` Code: `case "deleteBtn"`.

Comment: Yeah I changed that, it still does not work. I think it has to do with that I am "OnClientClick="return OpenPopup(this)">" and after that, it ignores the switch statement.

Comment: if the user clicks `noBtn`/`yesBtn` then the `CommandArgument` is that not `deleteContact`. But you haven't shown the js function `OpenPopup`

Comment: Look at the jQuery function I just implemented.

Comment: the noBtn and yesBtn shouldn't have server-side code of their own. They should just confirm yes/no client-side, and then leave the original action "deleteContact" to run if the user selected Yes, or cancel the action if they selected No. What you've got is a bit nonsensical.

Comment: Could you create a post for that? @ADyson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always return `false` from `OpenPopup`. Since you use.

```
OnClientClick="return OpenPopup(this)"
```

The postback will be canceled if you return `false` from `OnClientClick`. Instead you should return `true` if you want to perform the server-click.

```
function OpenPopup($this) {
    if ($($this).attr("disabled") === "disabled") {
        return false;
    }
    var module = $($this).parent().find("#myModal");
    module.show();
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target === module) {
            module.hide();
        }
    };

    return true;
}
```

Apart from that you have a typo, following should be the same `CommandName`:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="deleteContact"
```

Code:

```
case "deleteBtn"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your page you have

```
CommandName="deleteContact"
```

and in switch

```
case "deleteBtn"
```

they not match
in your switch you must use the same CommandName

```
case "deleteContact"
```

Comment: I changed that, it's not the problem.